# How to get exact IST time in php?

Tags: php, time, timezone

In php, I used date function  (eg: `date('Y-m-d h-m-s')`) it won’t displaying current time Please help me…

Comment: What does it mean by `it won't display current time ` ?

Comment: checkout `time()` and make sure your server _knows_ what time it is.

Comment: i want indian time.. plz help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update:

---

Here is how you can set time zone for your region:

```
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Mumbai');
}
```

---

It should work fine. Note also that you have not specified **minutes** correctly. Use `i` for minutes not `m`:

```
date('Y-m-d h-i-s')
```

And make sure to `echo` it:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h-i-s');
```

Comment: @Kushal: You said time was not displaying, i pointed out the issue :) If you want indian time, you should post another question "how to show indian time" to get more targeted answers :)

Comment: @Kushal. do you mean "indian time" as in d-m-Y H:i:s ?

Comment: @Kushal: You will need to set your time zone for that. Check out this function `date_default_timezone_set`

Comment: Asia/Mumbai is invalid timezone.

Comment: @sudip you are right... We can use `Asia/Kolkata` for Indian time.

Answer (score 17):

You want indian time.Here is my solution. You can use either `Asia/Calcutta` or `Asia/Kolkata`. both will return same time.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo date('Y-m-d h-i-s');
```

It worked for me.Try...

Comment: (Solution is for PHP 5 >= 5.1.0) I want you to refer these links also.
 [timeZones](http://in.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) [date_default_timezone_set](http://in.php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) according to ur need and then try

```
date('-r')
```

Comment: thanks for timezone link.... its works fine... my expected answer is date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo date("d-m-y / g:i a");

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
date('Y-m-d h-i-s',strtotime('+330 minute')); // where +330 min (difference of indian time zone with gmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
// this sets time zone to IST

echo date_format(new DateTime(),'d M Y H:i:s'); 
// this gives you date and time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kathmandu');
echo date('Y-m-d h-i-s');
```

This should work. You can see your timezone at http://www.worldtimezone.com.