# Lumen timezone related issue for select query

Tags: php, lumen

I have insert record to mysql database with create time object ,it is store in db proper time as per my timezone

while I have fire select query to get record it is not giving me proper record for example

if time in my database is 5:30pm then it shows in 12:00pm in my select query

I have change my timezone in .env file in APP_TIMEZONE but it gives me error like below,

> Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'IST' is invalid in
>   E:\xampp7\htdocs\centurylumen\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Application.php
>   on line 92

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get exact IST time in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151185/how-to-get-exact-ist-time-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Mumbai');
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```